# Jasmine Spy of Function inside Function async

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine, spyon

I have a function (functionUnderTest) that calls another function (functionToTest). Both return an observable.
I want to test if the function functionToTest is called when functionUnderTest is called. Therefore the functions are not in the same .ts file.

File1.ts:

```js
export function functionUnderTest(value): Observable<string> {
    return functionToTest(value);
}
```

File2.ts:

```js
export function functionToTest(value): Observable<string> {
  return of(value);
}
```

FYI: It is for my Angular 16 project

My testcode example:

```
import { functionUnderTest} from './File1';
import * as File2 from './File2';

describe("Test Suite", () => {
  it("test Function with spy", () => {

    spyOn(File2, 'functionToTest').and.callThrough();

    functionUnderTest('test parameter').subscribe(() => {

      expect(File2.functionToTest).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(File2.functionToTest).toHaveBeenCalledWith('test parameter');

    });
  });
});
```

The issue is, I get the Error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : functionToTest is not declared writable or has no setter
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

### Found a solution

When I add

```
"module": "commonjs",
```

To the *tsconfig.spec.json*-File inside the "compilerOptions" this will work!